# How to simplify the ratio 8.44:29.2?

Tags: ratio

I have tried 29.2/8.44 and tried multiplying this to get whole numbers but doesn't seem like it's working

Comment: Like, $$\frac{\frac{292}{10}}{\frac{844}{100}}\quad?$$

Comment: If you want a simple _appriximation_ it's not far from $0.3$, so $3:10$..

Comment: wouldn't the ratio $8.44$ to $29.2$ be $\frac {8.44}{29.2}$ and not $\frac {29.2}{8.44}$?  Well, in either case you simple "shift the decimals" so $\frac {8.44}{29.2} = \frac {84.4}{292} = \frac {844}{2920}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both by $100$ to get $844:2920$.

Then divide by the greatest common divisor.  I'm too lazy to figure out what the greatest common divisor so I'll just divide both sides by $4$ and then keep dividing until I can't any more.

Divide both sides by $4$

$211:730$

Well... can I divide any further?  $730 = 2*5*73$ and $211$ seems to be prime.  At any rate it isn't divisible by $2,5$ or $73$ so that's as for as we can divide.

Now, in hindsight we multiplied by $100$ and divided by $4$.  So that is the same as if we just multiplied by $25$ from the start.

Answer (score 0):

$844:2920$ divided by $4 = 211:730$.

$211$ is a prime number so it won't reduce further.